# Datetime calculation not working as expected on after update trigger but no errors

Tags: apex, after-trigger

I am trying to do some calculation based off datetime fields. I dont get any errors, but for some reason they don't work.

```
Case caseRecord = [SELECT Id, Next_Call_Date__c, Last_Call_Timestamp__c, Called__c  FROM Case WHERE Id = :newCase.Id];
     Datetime caseNextCallDate = caseRecord.Next_Call_Date__c;
     Datetime lastCallTime = caseRecord.Last_Call_Timestamp__c;
     Integer defaultTimeCustomSetting = Integer.valueOf(gs.Value__c);
     if(lastCallTime <= caseNextCallDate + (defaultTimeCustomSetting /1440)) {
        Case setCheckBoxTrue = new Case(Id = caseRecord.Id);
        caseRecord.Called__c = true;
        update setCheckBoxTrue;
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll need to give us more context. If you are trying to update a record that is contained in a trigger context variable, you should be using a _before_ trigger. If you're working on some other record, you'll need to perform DML to persist the change.

Comment: @DerekF This trigger is an after update trigger and I am not using the trigger context variable to update the checkbox. Basically if the time is within certain range it should check the checkbox to true. I have updated my original post with more code.

Comment: Just also want to mention there is another update happening to the same case record within this method just before the lines I posted above

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at that `if` block you have

```java
if(lastCallTime <= caseNextCallDate + (defaultTimeCustomSetting /1440)) {
    Case setCheckBoxTrue = new Case(Id = caseRecord.Id);
    caseRecord.Called__c = true;
    update setCheckBoxTrue;
}
```

You're setting `Called__c` on the `caseRecord` instance
but updating the `setCheckBoxTrue` instance (which only has the Id field set).

If that is indeed the code that you have in your org, the `setCheckBoxTrue` instance is useless, and can be removed. You should be performing DML on `caseRecord` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Derek. I saw that and fixed it, now I am doing the update on the caseRecord, still doesn't seem to be working. It seems like It is not getting into the if block at all even when the values are in range. Is there anything that I need to check on the custom setting that is used in the calculation. It has a value of 30 as of now. Also should we convert it to an integer when adding 30 minutes to the time?

Comment: @sumchans It sounds like you've still not provided enough context in your question for people to provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered, this should be a before update trigger, not an after update trigger. In addition, it appears you have a query in a loop, or you're otherwise not bulkifying your code.

You can optimize this to just:

```
Integer defaultTimeCustomSetting = Integer.valueOf(gs.Value__c/1440);
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Last_Call_Timestamp__c <= record.Next_Call_Date__c + defaultTimeCustomSetting) {
        record.Called__c = true;
    }
}
```

Note that adding a number to a DateTime increments by a number of *days*:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
System.debug(dt);
System.debug(dt+1);
```

Outputs:

```
13:54:20:004 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|2021-10-05 19:54:20
13:54:20:004 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2021-10-06 19:54:20
```

I'm not sure that's what you meant to do (dividing by 1440 suggests you're converting minutes to days, and discarding the fractional result), so this may not be the best approach. Why not just add the minutes directly?

```
Integer defaultTimeCustomSetting = gs.Value__c.intValue();
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Last_Call_Timestamp__c <= record.Next_Call_Date__c.addMinutes( defaultTimeCustomSetting)) {
        record.Called__c = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, this has to re-written as I now understand Case assigned to Omni channel doesn't trigger the case triggers instead the AgentWork triggers. Thats what I am trying to do